# Can i get a div height using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am working in web application .My asp page has two div tag. Based on first one div height i want to fix height of second one div. First one div height is changing dynamically. So i want to get height of first div so that i can fix the height of second div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theoretically you could. But the issue is about Css and Html. Just query for

> equal height columns with css

You could consider [this](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/) or [this](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/) sources.